# Need to get site URL in ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm using ASP.NET Core MVC 2.2 and I need to get the current URL of the website in the ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs.

This is because the URL is passed into the constructor of a library that I am configuring in that method.

```
services.AddScoped<IEmailProvider>(ep => new SendGridEmailProvider(Configuration["Email:SendGridApiKey"],
                Configuration.GetValue<bool>("Email:TestMode", true), 
                Configuration["Email:TestModeEmailAddresses"],
                Configuration["ENVIRONMENT"], 
                "THIS SHOULD BE THE APPLICATION URL"));
```

I'm pretty sure that I can't use standard dependency injection techniques within ConfigureServices as this is where all the dependency injection is actually set up!

Is there some way of getting the current URL of the request? I just need the base URL like www.site.com.

Comment: Can not you configure the url in the configuration ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I would rather not as it seems very prone to developer error. This system is deployed to multiple environments in various scenarios and I wouldn't want to rely on a dev entering the correct URL in the config. It would be a backup plan if what I'm asking is not possible though.

Comment: @Fiona-myaccessible.website Technically, the WebApp didn't know the base url at all at startup-time. That's because the WebApp usually lives behind a reverse proxy. In that case, the url could be any possible url.

Comment: A problem here is that the request is not available at the time of injection. Even with the deferred factory delegate. You would need to refactor your `SendGridEmailProvider` to access the request post construction to get the desired url.

Comment: The service configuration code runs at the application startup... So the code does not know the url of the application until a request is made.... If the application is going to be deployed in multiple environments it should be deployment pipeline's job to store proper values in the configuration file of deployment package.

Comment: Havent used that much of .Net Core, but could you not build up the URL, if the name of the App changes, that could be a problem, but if the only thing that changes is the hosting name, then just use the various ways to get the hostname in .NET

Comment: There is no "the URL". You may very well host this on localhost, and use IIS or another web server as a proxy. And a site can have multiple bindings. So why not simply store the desired URL in config as well?

Comment: What others said. Your current way is way more error prone than reading it from the configuration (which btw. can also be set as environment variable)

Comment: There's no such thing as a current URL. That's not how HTTP itself works. DNS resolves the domain to a server and that's it. The rest of the URL is passed in the HTTP body itself in the HOST header. The web server, *any* web server, reads that body and decides whether it wants to respond to that request or not. That's how a single server can serve multiple web sites on the same port. In a farm, multiple servers will serve the same web site.

Comment: `I just need the base URL like www.site.com.` what does that mean and why do you need it? Why not check an incoming request's HOST? If you want the host to generate URLs for emails, it's probably better to store the URL you want in a configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `HttpContext` to the DI container:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Then you can make a class to hold your `EmailOptions`:

```
public class EmailOptions
{
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
    public bool TestMode { get; set; }
    public string TestModeEmail { get; set; }
    public string Environment { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Then add a class to configure your `EmailOptions`:

```
public class ConfigureEmailOptions : IConfigureOptions<EmailOptions>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _environment;

    public ConfigureEmailOptions(
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
        IConfiguration configuration,
        IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _configuration = configuration;
        _environment = environment;
    }

    public void Configure(EmailOptions options)
    {
        options.ApiKey = _configuration["Email:SendGridApiKey"];
        options.TestMode = _configuration.GetValue<bool>("Email:TestMode", true);
        options.TestModeEmail = _configuration["Email:TestModeEmailAddresses"];
        options.Environment = _environment.EnvironmentName;
        options.Url = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Scheme + "://" + _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host + _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.PathBase;
    }
}
```

Then add your `EmailOptions` to the DI container:

```
services.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<EmailOptions>, ConfigureEmailOptions>();    
services.Configure<EmailOptions>(Configuration);
```

After that, you should be able to inject `IOptions<EmailOptions>` into your `SendGridEmailProvider`. (You could also inject `IHttpContextAccessor` directly into your `SendGridEmailProvider`, but that would be a tighter coupling.)

Comment: Configuration runs *before* the first request is received. There's no request and hence no HttpContext when configuration executes

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos "You can access other services from dependency injection while configuring options." Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options#use-di-services-to-configure-options-1 for details.

Comment: That link has nothing to do with this question. That link says nothing about HttpContext and incoming requests, it says you can use *DI Services* during configuration. There's *no* active request and hence no HttpContext during configuration.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Since this `IConfigureOptions` is being added as transient, it will be called every time it is injected into any service. You could also add it as scoped, in which case it would be called on each request. Either way, it will have full access to anything from the container at runtime (including `IHttpContextAccessor` which was added to the container with `services.AddHttpContextAccessor()`).

Comment: The solution proposed by @crgolden works just fine in .Net 5

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation with an ASP.Net 5 application, the solution proposed by @crgolden using `IHttpContextAccessor` for a Scoped service works just fine

I didn't implement the `IConfigureOptions` (surely is a good approach, but maybe an overkill for my case), I simply called `GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()` in the implementation factory method to get the instance of the service.

For this case it will be:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // [...]

    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

    services.AddScoped<IEmailProvider>(ep => new SendGridEmailProvider(Configuration["Email:SendGridApiKey"],
            Configuration.GetValue<bool>("Email:TestMode", true), 
            Configuration["Email:TestModeEmailAddresses"],
            Configuration["ENVIRONMENT"], 
            GetUrl(ep.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>())));
}

public string GetUrl(IHttpContextAccessor ca)
{
    return ca.HttpContext.Request.Scheme + "://" + ca.HttpContext.Request.Host + ca.HttpContext.Request.PathBase;
}
```